# how can split and print the array of mysql date in smarty with special symbol

Tags: php, smarty

i need to split and print the date value of a record and i got the splinted string but i can print in smarty  my code is given below

query

```
select  month(dob),day(dob),year(dob) from user_details
```

the output

```
$us=array{["day(usr_dob)"]=>  string(1) "5" ["month(usr_dob)"]=>  string(1) "3" ["year(usr_dob)"]=>  string(1) "0"}`*
```

i need to call the array inducitualy

```
{$us.day(usr_dob)}
```

but the page show error.. how can i will print the value also i need to check the value is match with any number value

ple help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use aliases?

```
select  month(dob) as month, day(dob) as day, year(dob) as year from user_details
```